# Docusign API Invalid Token Autorization - Trying to get envelopes data

Tags: google-apps-script, docusignapi

I can't use the acess token i'm generating to get my envelopes data from Docusign API. The token generation is working, but the API calls gives me "code 401. Truncated server response: {"errorCode":"AUTHORIZATION_INVALID_TOKEN","message":"The access token provided is expired, revoked or malformed."

Context: I'm trying to get all my envelopes data from Docusign and paste it in google sheets using Google Apps Script. I did not write the part where i organize the json response yet.

I managed to automatically create an acess token by creating an app in Docusign Developes and using its keys.

When i try to call the api to fetch the envelopes data using my function that generates the token, i get code 401.

Here's the code i'm using (typed x in the id's to be sure i'm using the correct id's with the correct sizes):

```
function getAllEnvelopes() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var wsapi = ss.getSheetByName("api");
  var apiUrl = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/xxxxxxxx/envelopes";
  var headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " +  getAccessToken()// replace with your DocuSign access token
  };
  Logger.log(headers);
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl, {
    "headers": headers,"contentType": 'application/json'});
  var responseData = response.getContentText();
  var envelopes = JSON.parse(responseData).envelopes;
  Logger.log(envelopes);
  wsapi.getRange(1,1).setValue(envelopes);
  // process the envelopes data as needed
}

function getAccessToken() {
  // replace with your DocuSign API key and secret
  var apiKey = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
  var apiSecret = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
  var tokenUrl = "https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token";
  var headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  };
  var payload = {
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "client_id": apiKey,
    "client_secret": apiSecret,
    "scope": "signature"
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(tokenUrl, {
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": headers,
    "payload": payload
  });
  var responseData = response.getContentText();
  var accessToken = JSON.parse(responseData).access_token;
  Logger.log(accessToken);
  return accessToken;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This does not show how you obtained the token. These tokens expire after 8 hours, you cannot use a token unless it is from the same account.

Comment: This also does not look like one of DocuSign's OAuth flows. Client Credentials flow is used only for DocuSign Connect OAuth.

Comment: Ok, so what kind of procedure i have to follow in order to authenticate this "get envelopes" code?

Comment: One of the methods listed here: https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/choose/

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I tried the Implicit Grant Token method from https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/implicit/implicit-get-token/ and it worked.

I managed to get an API response but only from my developers account. I hope it works in production after following the Go-Live process.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).